# How to read folium polygon popup in Python

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

Is there a way to return the coordinates in the folium polygon draw popup back into Python?

[image]

I can use Python to create html / JS to create the map, but can't figure out how to return the JS data back to Python.

Comment: Hi Josh, that's not possible with folium. folium is a one way street from Python to html/JS. Maybe you can check out ipyleaflet? https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet Another option is to store your drawn polygon to a file and load that in Python. But I don't know your exact requirements, so not sure if that'd work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will certainly look into ipyleaflet. Storing the polygon to file sounds like a great idea. Is that a feature of folium? I can't find info on that.

Comment: The Draw plug-in, which I assume you are using, has an export option. If you set it to True a button to save as a file will be added to the map. You can check the docs here: https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/plugins.html#folium-plugins

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I finally gave up trying to make this work with Folium and switched to Leaflet. I now use Python to create a json file, have Leaflet read the file and build the map, then send the results of the drawing tool back to Python.